# calculate mutual information using joint probability distribution table

Tags: information-theory

let us suppose we have following joint probability distribution table
[image]

i would like to calculate mutual information between two variable,  first of all i have calculated  marginal distributions
[image]

and  i used following formula
[image]

which  i have considered as this one
[image]

Using excel  I have calculated following table
[image]

zero  is written because  it is accepted  generally that

$0*log(0)=0$

so finally i got  following result

```
0.334497797
```

because it is different from  zero, that means that  these two  random variable  are not independent right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all right.

> because it is different from zero, that means that these two random variable are not independent right?

Yes. That can also be seen by checking that the joint probability doesn't equal the product of the marginals (at least for some values). For example $P(X=0,Y=0)=0.2$ while $P(X=0)P(Y=0)= 0.5 \times 0.3 = 0.15$

Comment: thanks for  reply, what about if  we dont have  any  information about their joint distribution? how can we check  their independence?

Comment: @datodatuashvili If you only have the marginals, you can't know if they are independent. The joint distribution is what fully characterizes a pair of random variables. For checking non-independence , in some cases a less complete description might suffice: for example, non-zero covariance implies non-independent variables (but not the reverse). Also, if the "support" region (region of the domain where the joint probability function is non-zero) is not a rectangle (perhaps unbounded) or a cartesian product of rectangles, then they are not independent.

Comment: wish you good night thanks for your  reply